# How to auto select items in listview when fragment in view pager comes into existence in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have an app which contains view pager with three fragment that contains listview with some data. Fragment one is by default visible when we launch an app and when I select an item lets say index 2 and change fragment from 1 to 2 and when I come back from fragment 2 to 1 I want index 2 of fragment one listview which I was earlier selected should disable.How do I do that

code:-

```
 mAdapter = new UserListingAdapter(mContext, dataSet, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    mRecyclerList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerList.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    mRecyclerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: Add some flag variable in your list model class, and  if list item is selected then update the flag value. And check if flag value is set then just disable the list item in adapter.

Comment: view.setEnable(false) to disable the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by overriding `setUserVisibleHint()` in your `Fragment` as:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        //TODO:YOUR CODE TO TOGGLE/CLEAR SELECTIONS
    }
}
```